# Hydra: Referring to a config group option in the parent directory

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I can't find a way to load config group options from parent directories in hydra.
E.g. here I want to load the config group option from `datamodule/wikipedia1m.yaml` from `variant/default.yaml` but it does not give what I expected.

Here are my hydra setup:

---

```
conf
├── config.yaml
├── datamodule
│   ├── dummy.yaml
│   └── wikipedia1m.yaml
├── task
│   ├── concat_t5_base.yaml
│   ├── concat.yaml
└── variant
    └── default.yaml
```

`config.yaml`

```
defaults:
  - variant: default
  - _self_
```

`variant/default.yaml`

```
# @package _global_

task: concat_t5_base
datamodule: wikipedia1m
```

---

**Resulting config**:

```
  task: concat_t5_base
  datamodule: wikipedia1m
```

**Expected config**:

```
  task:
    _target_: xxx
    model_name: t5-base
    shuffle_labels: true
  datamodule:
    _target_: xxx
    num_workers: 4
    batch_size: 8
```

Any idea on how to achieve the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

This is supported in Hydra 1.1 and newer.
You need a defaults list in variant.yaml, and you need to refer to the parent parent with a `/` prefix.

What you are trying to do is described in the [Configuring Experiments](https://hydra.cc/docs/patterns/configuring_experiments/) page.